# How much food does Nibbler require in order to produce one of his dense 1 pound=10,000 pounds power packed pellets of dark matter?

Tags: futurama

[Futurama Wiki](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_matter) says:(Dark matter) is the densest, and therefore heaviest, substance in the universe, with each ball that Nibbler produces weighing as much as 1000 suns.

Professor Farnsworth says dark matter is so dense that

> "each pound of it weighs over ten thousand pounds."

Nibbler himself admits

> "We live long and are celebrated poopers"

He has an enormous appetite. How much food does Nibbler *require* in order to produce one of his dense 1 pound=10,000 pounds power packed pellets of dark matter?

Comment: I just watched this last night when all of the Nibblonians? were in cages being forced to defecate; they were fed 4 chickens in between bowel evacuations. There was also prune juice on the wall.

Comment: Are you saying they are 4 chickens a pounders? What happens when they eat like they did on planet Vergon 6?

Comment: More poop? I wasn't saying it as a definitive answer, just noticed that he pooped, ate 4 chickens, and pooped again.

Comment: @MajorStackings: 4 chickens ... *and prune juice*. Presumably there was no prune juice on Vergon 6.

Comment: I am also including a comment with the word poop in it.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I tried keeping my first comment devoid of "poop", but it starts to sound pretentious when you say "More defecation?"

Comment: @NominSim Maybe the chicken poops weren't as dense? One pound only weighed 12 pounds or so.

Comment: Or maybe its a gag or exaggeration. We are remembering this is a science fiction comedy? Nothing they say should be taken too seriously. Each sphere weighed as much as a thousand suns? The Earth would implode on that spot if each one actually did have that much mass. Yes, they are impressively massive but nothing as big as all that. 1000 suns sounds more massive than a 1000 pounds. In Futurama, you don't just go to the top, YOU GO OVER IT!

Comment: @NominSim I think your comment is probably the best answer for this, given it shows on screen some quantity of food between poops.

Comment: @MajorStackings Converted my comment into a more loquacious answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Direct-to-DVD film [Bender's Game](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Game),  the Nibblonians were in cages being forced to defecate; and were fed 4 chickens in between bowel evacuations. There was also prune juice on the wall.

Seeing as how it was Mom that was caging them and harvesting their dark matter, it is likely that this is all they needed in order to produce one dark matter "pellet". (Mom is notoriously ruthless and stringent.)

Answer (score 3):

In the episode when Nibbler first meets the gang, he eats all of the animals that were collected by the Planet Express crew:

- Purple Fruit Snake
- Sharktopus
- Chilean Space Bass
- Parasitic Puppy
- Gretchen Mole
- Windy Shrimp
- Vampire Slug
- Excommunicated Cardinal
- Four-Legged Mimic
- Molotov Cockatoo
- Hermaphlamingos

  x2 and after all of that he only produced one ball of dark matter. ([Source for list of animals](http://theinfosphere.org/Vergon_6))